# NSJSONSerialization - "Unexpected end of file during string parse"

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

i have some wired issue when Parsing some REST-Response. The problem is, that i can't reproduce it . Sometimes it happens, and I have no corresponding information in the error logs.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unexpected end of file during string parse (expected low-surrogate code point
but did not find one).) UserInfo=0x157bddb0 {NSDebugDescription=Unexpected end of file during string parse (expected low-surrogate code point but did not find one).}
```

I'm sorry, I'm not allowed to give you any information from the JSON-Response because of sensitive user data (It only appears on some in-house accounts, where the error log level is set low to detect this issue).

Some other information:

- The JSON is valid (Checked via http://jsonlint.com/)
- When trying to reproduce this issue i get other NSError Descriptions, like:

  - Character at position XYZ is invalid
  - Invalid Object
  - ...

**UPDATE 1:** Parse mechanism (Extension of NSData)

```
- (NSDictionary *)objectFromJSONDataWithError:(NSError **)error {
    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: self
                                                               options: 0
                                                                 error: error];

    return jsonObject;
}
```

**Update 2:** NSOperation for downloading data - Content of main() --> Calls function in Update 1

```
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = nil;

for (NSInteger i=0; i<kMaxRequestRetry; i++) {
    data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                 returningResponse: &response
                                             error: &error];

    if (!error) {
        // Handling internal errors and retry mechanism
    }

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
}

// Check http status code
NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode >= 300) {
    CLogWarn(@"Request finished with status code = %d", (int)statusCode);
}

// Evaluate response
if (error) {
    CLogError(@"%@", error);
    [self requestFinishedWithResult:@"{\"errorCode\":99}";
    return;
} else {
    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSDictionary *responseDic = [data objectFromJSONDataWithError:&parseError];

    // Detect parse issues
    if (parseError) {
        CLogError(@"JSONParse-Error: %@", parseError);
        [self requestFinishedWithResult:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"errorCode\":%d}", (11000 + (int)parseError.code)]];
        return;
    }

    // Success handling
}
```

**Update 3:** JSON-Object structure

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "conversations": [
      {
          "address": "+43664000000",
          "snippet": "This is an dummy text",
          "messagesUnread": 1,
          "messagesUnsent": 2,
          "messages": 9,
          "maxMessageId": 151672,
          "dateLastMessage": 1386353756858
      }
  ]
}
```

I'm happy for any information or tips how to force this error code.

Best Regards,
Chris

Comment: The error messages indicate that you try to parse an *incomplete* JSON object. Without more information (e.g. *how* the parsing is done) it is probably difficult to help.

Comment: how about showing the JSON itself that fails maybe stripping sensitive data?

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela: See Update 1 - It works for all other 15 Requests. I think there must be some corrupt chars in some json values

Comment: @MartinR: In this case the JSON is about 1000 lines long (Messenger App). Because I work with an valid JSON, I think it must be some chars in the JSON obejct (Message-Data = String).

Comment: @Chris: From where is objectFromJSONDataWithError called? (A common error is that data is read in chunks, and each chunk is parsed separately.)

Comment: Chris, don't *assume* your JSON is "valid" when you feed the parser. You didn't show us *how* you get that JSON data. So, it's possible that it is cut off, or not complete. For testing purposes, you should log the JSON *data* (not a NSString representation, since converting to a NSString may fail) into some file for further analysis.

Comment: @MartinR: Added downloadmechanism + parse call in Update 2

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: Download is completed. As I said, all the date i stuck into the parser seems to be valid and fully downloaded (I have the logs).

Comment: Are you receiving any encrypted data in JSON response?

Comment: @TechNet-Weblineindia: Nope. Not in this request. It works fine but sometimes this issue happens. Maybe it's in combination with messages from our Win8.1 App but I haven't figured it out yet. I would be happy if i could reproduce this issue :D

Comment: @ChristophL The way you check for errors is generally not correct. Please read the docs carefully: basically, an error output parameter (a pointer to a NSError*) is only set IFF the corresponding method signaled an error via its _return value_. So, *first* check the return value, and IFF this indicates an error, read the error object. Otherwise, the error object may be not nil, yet completely garbage. You also don't check the MIME type of the response. So, it can be HTML or binary, or whatever which you pass through the parser.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thanks for that information to NSError. I don't copy all the code to the example above. Mime-Type check is also included. In my case, the result of the JSON-Parse is nil and only the error is set to that one above. In my case, the response IS AN VALID JSON OBJECT (I checkt this 100 times now). I need to reproduce that error to detect the issue, but i don't know when it could appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. The "snippet" in the json object contains a substring from the original message. Our API (written in java) use the substring method and this cuts of the surrogate-pair. The android and windows clients have no problem with this and only show an invalid char, but the NSJSONSerialization throws this error.

Got an tip via the apple dev forum: https://devforums.apple.com/message/961738#961738

Comment: What was the tip, link for apple forum stopped working.

Answer (score 5):

**Issue Reproduction**

Cause of this issue is that the `string` in `json` contains illegal Unicode Point. The following code can reproduce this issue.

```
NSString* test = @"{\"\\ud801\" : 1}";
NSError* error = nil;
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
```

---

**Solution**

According to [Readme.md in JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit#json-to-objective-c-primitive-mapping-details), you can use `JSONKit` as an additional parser. e.g.

```
 id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:options error:&error];
 if (error) {          
     error = nil;
     result = [data objectFromJSONDataWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionLooseUnicode error:& error];   // use JSONKit
 }
```